# How feasible is a brick veneer fake wall?

Tags: walls, brick, uk, television

We want to brick veneer our chimney breast (Which has a TV mounted to it) but I had a thought that would allow us to hide the wires, brick veneer the wall and also keep the wall behind in a clean state that would allow us to easily revert the brick veneer if we so wish. However... I'm most certainly a DIYer and don't want to jump head first into it without exploring whether or not it is a wise idea.

My plan is to use a piece of ply wood that is the same size as the chimney breast.

1. Channel routes for the TV cables into the back side of the plywood.
2. Cut hole out of the plywood for the TV mounting bracket.
3. Apply brick veneer/brick slips to the front side of the plywood with the mortar leaving 8 exposed holes around the edges for mounting purposes.
4. Attach plywood to chimney breast with 8 large screws and rawl plugs.

More information:

- The chimney breast is not plaster, it is some form of brick or concrete.
- The fireplace is not in use. It is blocked up and has an electric fire mounted in it's place. (never used)
- The house is a UK semi detached 1960s/1970s construction
- The [this](http://www.homedepot.com/hdus/en_US/DTCCOMNEW/fetch/DIY_Projects_and_Ideas/Electrical/Guides/wall-mounting-a-flat-screen-tv-HT-PG-EL-Step05.jpg) is the wall mount bracket for the TV

Does this sound like a wise idea? I've had concerns over the weight of the brick slip tiles but having never undertaken a task like this before I'm not sure.

Here is a pic of the wall in question, the bit above the mantle piece is the bit we would like to brick veneer

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMklM.jpg]

Comment: With it being newer construction, it could be drywall. I see nothing that suggests it being brick or concrete which needs an entirely different approach than hollow wall construction, which I refer loosely to as wood or steel framing with a cover of sheetrock or plaster or other solid suface over the face of the framing. If you mounted the tv in the pic you just posted, what leads you to think brick or concrete? If it was much older construction, I would say yes, solid brick with plaster finish, but I dare say, not with 60-70's construction. Maybe UK is drastically different than the US??

Comment: Even brick veneer is heavy stuff.  There's a process for producing a brick look that might simplify things for you.  It uses a layer of a material like drywall mud.  A rectangular template that looks like a cookie cutter is pressed into it to create the brick pattern.  You can paint everything to look like painted brick, or get fancy and paint just the "brick" surfaces to look like bricks.  They also make various faux brick panels, like this http://www.homedepot.com/p/1-4-in-x-48-in-x-96-in-Kingston-Brick-Hardboard-Wall-Panel-278844/205683640,

Comment: Another example: https://gadgetshopping.co/products/3d-self-adhesive-wall-stickers.  Here's a way to make it from styrofoam: http://ourdailyideas.com/diy-easy-faux-brick-wall-panel/.  A link on replicating the texture: http://www.house-painting-info.com/articles/painting-faux-brick/#.WUW8M9y1uM8.  An article on the drywall mud method: http://www.plumdoodles.com/faux-bricks-drywall-mud/.

Comment: Thanks for that guys, some good alternatives I'll look into.

Comment: @jack, I don't know for sure but I've replaced a couple of electrical outlets in these walls and they've been solid brick or blocks of some kind with some form of yellowy concrete style material in there too. Also to mount the TV I had to use the hammer setting on the drill and put a bit of force behind it. Never had to be that forceful in a house with hollow walls?

Comment: No I have not any difficulty drilling in regular frame walls. You have very solid construction there I must say

Comment: What happened here? Did you end up doing a real brick veneer, or did you use something fake, but brick-like? If one of the answers helped you, give it a check mark, if not, write up what you did as your own answer and check mark that!

Comment: @FreeMan I didn't end up going for any of the methods as my plaster was already weak. Not sure that really 'answers' the question though. I've accepted Erics answer below as the most helpful for future searchers though.

Comment: That's an excellent philosophy for selecting an answer in that situation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually did a very similar thing this year. I thought about making a "fake brick wall" as you are now. My main concern, as is yours, is weight. The weight of all those bricks adds up to be quite a bit to be supported from the wall. You may want to add up your weight and compare with veneer ones. What I eventually concluded was to use brick veneer tiles similar to these guys:

[Menards Brick Veneer](https://www.menards.com/main/flooring-rugs/tile-stone/quarry-tile/versatile-reg-2-3-4-x-7-5-8-tumbled-thin-brick-veneer-for-floors-and-walls/p-1444436120817-c-6560.htm?tid=-4094376965180368286&ipos=18)

In terms of putting them up, I followed an identical process for laying tiles down since they are tiles:

1. Mix up Mastic / Mortar [Product like this one](https://www.menards.com/main/flooring-rugs/tile-stone/tile-installation-maintenance/tile-mortar-mastics/tec-reg-ultimate-large-tile-mortar-383-40-pounds/p-1444432137763-c-6586.htm?tid=-3303792509810757941&ipos=10)
2. Lay a bit of Mastic down on wall. Only do a small section at a time like 4 bricks width so it doesn't dry out too quickly
3. Place bricks on wall. Use spacers similar to those in tilework to keep a uniform spacing. Aim to have the brick middle at the edge of the prior row's brick.
4. When to the end of a row, cut last brick accordingly.
5. Repeat until all rows are done.
6. After all bricks have been placed up, go back with grout. Put grount in a plastic bag with the tip cut off and fill in the cracks like a cake decorator. Be very careful not to get any on the face of the bricks though! It is very hard to get off from the face.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Eric. I think that using the tiling system on the wall is a bit out of my league unfortunately. I think ideally I would like an internal system that replicates this: https://www.voxpanels.co.uk/external-cladding/ as this would be easiest even if it doesn't look as realistic.

Comment: @ScottHarrison Either way I would be mindful of weight as you said. Weight per one brick x number of bricks can become very high quickly

Answer (score -1):

I think you might have better results with construction adhesive rather than mortar for sticking the brick chips. Mortar would just be for the joints, for appearance sake.

In the US this was popular decades ago - and I have to say, I never saw one that looked convincingly like real bricks.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I think it would be tough to get right but always willing to try. I think I may try some of the alternatives mentioned above though first as they seem less involved and less risky in terms of weight on the wall and potential for something to go wrong

Comment: The "decades ago" brick you are referring to was the fake brick fad of the 70's...basically plastic or a textured composite. Popular today is brick veneer...It's REAL brick...just thinner than a full-size brick. Obviously not for structural use. I did it in my home office and would pay good money if you were able to tell the difference - both visually and by touch.

Comment: You are incorrect. It was thin slices of real brick. Indeed, the primary brand of the time claims to have been at it since 1954 and is still in business.